# Python IDE with keyword-specific syntax highlighting seen in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, ide

Sublime Text 3's syntax highlighting formats different Python keywords like 'class', 'def', and 'lambda' from other keywords like 'with', 'for', and 'if'. I find this helpful and aesthetically pleasing. I am looking for a Python IDE that supports this feature. I have not been able to find this feature in PyCharm, Komodo, or PyDev, and I am afraid that these editors simply cannot differentiate Python keywords; they end up formatting all Python keywords as the same for syntax highlighting.

Comment: And your erason for not using Sublime Text 3 is?

Comment: Which operating system? Must it be free, or do you have a budget? Welcome aboard. The more that you help us, the more that we can help you. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This keyword differing was done in [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/), [SynWrite](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editors. Both apps have some IDE features, for few languages, e.g. **Python Intel** plugin for Python.